# Why does SIP trace shows UAS URI twice in VIA of 200 OK

Tags: sip

I do have the screenshot of the attatched SIP Trace from Request (Invite) till the Response (OK).

I have two questions:

1) Why does the UAS (Responder) appear twice in the VIA field. This seems as if the flow on application level is:
(217.10.79.9 -> 172.20.40.4 -> 217.10.79.9 -> 139.6.19.184 -> Recorder (Wireshark) -> 139.6.19.188.

2) The client 139.6.19.188 appears to be behind NAT. Why do I find the gateway IP 139.6.19.184 in the VIA. Does that mean the gateway or router has a SIP Proxy included?

Thank you. If there are any information missing or questions please feel free to ask. I am happy for any help.

[image: snap]

Comment: In addition, the record-route  headers indicates two times 217.10.79.9 ; it seems that there is a loop. Could you elaborate your question please ; is there an actual problem? And maybe describe what you expect compare to what you observe in traces.

Comment: Thanks for the response in this case I would assume that the VIA and Record-Route has the same information, or at least at certain point in time have had the same information. There is no problem, I would just like to understand the network from the trace.